# How can you load maps from Geoserver using https?

Tags: java, tomcat, geoserver

How would I go about configuring Geoserver to only load from an https address? I have been combing the web and cannot find any solution.

Comment: a bit off topic but for more security you could even configure geoserver to run with SSL http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/cert/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this question is not exactly related to geoserver.

You should configure your java application server (tomcat or whatever) [to use https](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). Geoserver will *inherit* that configuration

If you are using tomcat you can try to follow [this instructions](http://www.itworld.com/article/2769041/development/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-always-require-https.html). Or as stated in the comments, now geoserver doc also includes [how to configure tomcat for ssl](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/cert/index.html#configure-tomcat-for-ssl).

Comment: GeoServer docs cover this: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/cert/index.html#configure-tomcat-for-ssl

Answer (score 3):

If you make use of a proxy, e.g. Nginx. Make sure to set the correct Proxy Url in GeoServer. If not set correctly, GeoServer will advertise with HTTP when asked for it's capabilities. You can check it yourself by opening WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd in your browser.

https://youserver.com/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd

or

https://youserver.com/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_MS_Capabilities.dtd